# Do not save state for print page

Tags: jsf, lifecycle, savestate

For page for print, which is text only, no command link/button to click, there is no need to save states for print pages. Is there a way to tell JSF not to save states? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JSF already won't save state anyway if the view does not contain any `<h:form>`. So there's nothing to worry about.

The `<f:view transient="true">`, which enables stateless mode since Mojarra 2.1.19, would not have any additional advantage if the view already doesn't contain any `<h:form>`.

Comment: In our case, one JSF page is used for print/normal pages. can transient=#{bean.transient} ? so that one jsf page can be used for both transient and non-transient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of Mojarra you can do this:

```
<f:view transient="true">
    Your page
</f:view>
```

But I don't think that doing this will have any significant positive effect on your application.

Comment: Memory usage is critial for us. So we config numberOfViews=2, numberOfLogicalViews=2. print pages should not consume memory for the state saving. thanks.